# wrong return value by function

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, network-programming, client-server

I developed on program in c++ in which i want to store clientadd,clientport,servaddr,servport 
in stl map.
I am able to pass the values to map and display from map.
The values which i display showing correctly for (clientadd,clientport,servport)
but wrong for servaddr.

```
map<int, Values> items;

Values connection (inet_ntoa(clientaddr.sin_addr),ntohs(clientaddr.sin_port),inet_ntoa(servaddr.sin_addr),ntohs(servaddr.sin_port));


items.insert(pair<int, Values> (0, connection));

cout << "Size of the items map : " << items.size() << endl;

map<int,Values>::const_iterator itemsIterator = items.begin();

while(itemsIterator != items.end() )
{
  Values item = itemsIterator->second;
  item.printValues();
  itemsIterator++; //make the iterator point to the next pair in the map
}

class Values
{
private:
char *C_addr;
int C_port;
char *S_addr;
int S_port;

public:
Values(char*,int,char*,int);
void printValues();
};

Values :: Values(char *faddr,int fport,char *gwaddr,int gport)
{
C_addr=faddr;
C_port=fport;
S_addr=gwaddr;
S_port=gport;
}

void Values::printValues()
{
cout << C_addr<<":" <<C_port<<   ":" << S_addr <<":" <<S_port << endl;
}
```

output i am expecting

127.0.0.1  :  any port no  :  0.0.0.0  : any port no

(i.e client addr,client port,serv addr, serv port)

but i am getting output like this

127.0.0.1 : any port no : 127.0.0.1  :  any port no

Comment: How are you setting `char *gwaddr` in the constructor call? Can you add this code to your question please.

Comment: atualy i got thos values from client connection so thos are depend upon which client connected to server.there i added all necessary code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_ntoa) of `inet_ntoa`:

> The string is returned in a statically allocated buffer, which subsequent calls will overwrite.

So both constructor arguments point to the same buffer, filled with whichever address happened to be written last. If some other code were to call `inet_ntoa` again, then they would become even wronger.

Use `std::string`, rather than pointers, to keep hold of a copy of the string.